# XPath: how to extract first line of multi-line attribute value?

Tags: xpath

For example:

```
<doc>
    <elem attr="firstLine &x0a; secondLine"/>
    <elem attr="1stLine"/>
</doc>
```

The need is to get the first line, when there are many

From the example above, we want to get { 'firstLine', '1stLine'}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
substring-before(/*/elem[1]/@attr, '&#x0A;')
```

**Here is an XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="substring-before(/*/elem[1]/@attr, '&#x0A;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be well-formed !!!):

```
<doc>
    <elem attr="firstLine &#x0a; secondLine"/>
    <elem attr="1stLine"/>
</doc>
```

**it evaluates the XPath expression and outputs the result of this evaluation**:

```
firstLine
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XPath 2.0, you can use [`tokenize()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)